# Show warnings from mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, rds

I'm running a job from a Linux box to an Amazon RDS (MySQL) that pumps in about 1GB of data via mysqlimport. It runs flawlessly, however, when I attempt the exact same command with windows I get 10000s of warnings but I cannot find a way to output those.

ASAIK, mysqlimport is the ONLY way to get large chunks of data into RDS. Any tips on outputting those warnings or if anyone has any real-world alternative examples would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to show warnings from `mysqlimport`. I'm not familiar with Amazon RDS, but why didn't you use `LOAD DATA (LOCAL) INFILE` and `SHOW WARNINGS`? Don't you have privileges?

Comment: Silly me. I was following their guide.. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933

LOAD DATA (LOCAL) INFILE worked quite well.